# Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : Looping For

Tags: r, loops, google-cloud-platform

I am working with large data. I have 2 datasets as ORIGIN and DESTINATION.  Using google API, I would like to compute the direction from ORIGIN dataset to DESTINATION dataset. The data is as follows:

```
Origin(masterdata):
No xcoord  ycoord
1 109.6663 -6.897970
2 109.6584 -6.897511
3 109.6519 -6.893822
4 109.6586 -6.896936
5 109.6651 -6.897484

Destination(xystation3375)
No Long    Lat
1 109.6644 -6.889696
2 109.7008 -6.902980


key = "Google API
dataset_origin <- as.data.frame(masterdata[1:500,])
dataset_dest <- as.data.frame(xystation3375)

n = nrow(dataset_origin)

dest <- dataset_dest
k = nrow(dest)

data_od <- NULL
for(j in 1:k){
  for(i in 1:n){
    doc = mp_directions(
      origin = as.double(c(dataset_origin$xcoord[i],dataset_origin$ycoord[i])), #origin_ke-i. looping dari 1-20
      destination = as.double(c(dest$lng[j],dest$lat[j])), #destination ke_j; looping dari 1-3
      alternatives = TRUE,
      key = key,
      quiet = TRUE
    )

route = as.data.frame(mp_get_routes(doc))
route2 = cbind(route[1:7],
               rep(dataset_origin$D_NOP[i],nrow(route)),
               rep(dataset_origin$xcoord[i],nrow(route)),
               rep(dataset_origin$ycoord[i],nrow(route)),
               rep(dest$`place_name(xystation3375)`[j],nrow(route))
               )
data_od <- rbind.data.frame(data_od,route2,make.row.names = FALSE)


 }
}
```

After execution, I found error:

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  argument is missing, with no default
```

Any solution for that error?
Thank you

Comment: (1) Incomplete code (not-closed `key` string, visually identifiable with SO's code syntax highlighting), please fix, and please ensure it is as close as needed to what you are using. (2) Why are you reaching out to google api for a simple bearing? You can use the `geosphere` package to calculate the bearing without need for network connections, and it will be significantly faster.

Answer (score 1):

Without google-api, this can be done locally with the `geosphere` package:

```r
dists <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(xystation3375)), function(rn) {
  geosphere::distHaversine(masterdata[,c("xcoord","ycoord")], xystation3375[rn,c("Long","Lat")])
})

dists
#           [,1]     [,2]
# [1,]  944.6891 3853.277
# [2,] 1093.8555 4725.144
# [3,] 1455.7938 5499.434
# [4,] 1029.7686 4711.942
# [5,]  870.4009 3992.477
```

In `dists`, each row corresponds to the row of `masterdata`; each column corresponds to each row of `xystation3375`. If you want to convert this into a longer table using the two `No` columns, you can use

```r
dimnames(dists) <- list(masterdata$No, xystation3375$No)
as.data.frame.table(dists)
#    Var1 Var2      Freq
# 1     1    1  944.6891
# 2     2    1 1093.8555
# 3     3    1 1455.7938
# 4     4    1 1029.7686
# 5     5    1  870.4009
# 6     1    2 3853.2772
# 7     2    2 4725.1437
# 8     3    2 5499.4340
# 9     4    2 4711.9420
# 10    5    2 3992.4767
```

where `Var1` is `masterdata$No`.