# For Loop to calculate Euclidean distance in R using geosphere package

Tags: r, loops

I have succeeded following the instruction at [Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : Looping For](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65182129/error-in-data-frame-check-names-false-looping-for/65182481#65182481) to calculate the distance from ORIGIN to DESTINATION using geosphere package. And now, I find new trouble when I would like to do the same operation with a different dataset. I have 2 datasets as follows:

```
ORIGIN (MASTERDATA)
NO xcoord    ycoord
1  109.6663  -6.897970
2  109.6584  -6.897511
3  109.6519  -6.893822
4  109.6586  -6.896936
5  109.6651  -6.897484

DESTINATON (SMP)
NO x_SMP    y_SMP
1  109.6652  -6.898086
2  109.6501  -6.910931
3  109.6579  -6.891705
4  109.6579  -6.891705
5  109.6579  -6.891705
```

From 2 datasets above, I would like to calculate the distance each row. Row 1 of ORIGIN dataset will meet Row 1 of DESTINATION dataset, the idea is like this:

```
ORIGIN   DESTINATION
Row 1 -> Row 1 : Distance 1
Row 2 -> Row 2 : Distance 2
Row 3 -> Row 3 : Distance 3
Row 4 -> Row 4 : Distance 4
Row 5 -> Row 5 : DIstance 5
```

For those goals, I operate `For Loop` to calculate distance each row using `geosphere` package, the syntax is as follows:

```
library(geosphere)
n = nrow(masterdata)
    datalist = list()

for (i in 1:n) {
  # ... make some data
  dat <- distm(c(masterdata$xcoord[i], masterdata$ycoord[i]), c(masterdata$x_SMP[i], masterdata$y_SMP[i]), fun = distHaversine)
  dat$i <- i 
  datalist[[i]] <- dat
}

big_data = do.call(cbind, datalist)
```

Using that syntax, I would like to append the data frame with the result of loops operation. After execution, I find the result is not like what I expect. The data frame should have n-row. The result, I only have 1 row.

Thank you

Comment: [`geosphere::distm`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/geosphere/versions/1.5-10/topics/distm) takes whole vectors/matrices so you should not need to loop. `dist <- distm(masterdata[c("xcoord", "ycoord")], masterdata[c("x_SMP", "y_SMP")], fun = distHaversine)` Please [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) the many `r` distance questions that use `geosphere`.

Answer (score 0):

The dead simple solution with the code you have is just get rid of `dat$i` in your for-loop and transpose the vector `big_data` before you add it to `masterdata`.

```
NO = c(1,2,3,4,5)
xcoord = c(109.6663, 109.6584, 109.6519, 109.6586, 109.6651)
ycoord = c(-6.897970, -6.897511, -6.893822, -6.896936, -6.897484)
x_SMP = c(109.6652, 109.6501, 109.6579, 109.6579, 109.6579)
y_SMP = c(-6.898086, -6.910931, -6.891705, -6.891705, -6.891705)

masterdata = data.frame("NO" = NO, "xcoord" = xcoord, "ycoord" = ycoord, "x_SMP" = x_SMP, "y_SMP" = y_SMP)

library(geosphere)
n = nrow(masterdata)
datalist = list()

for (i in 1:n) {
  # ... make some data
  dat <- distm(c(masterdata$xcoord[i], masterdata$ycoord[i]), c(masterdata$x_SMP[i], masterdata$y_SMP[i]), fun = distHaversine)
  datalist[[i]] <- dat
}

big_data = do.call(cbind, datalist)
masterdata['distance'] = t(big_data)
```

I'll see if I can't find a more elegant solution in the meantime.

*Edited

Don't know why I just didn't spare an extra two minutes before answering (brain's a little slow today), but just vectorize your code by doing the following

```
masterdata['distance'] = distHaversine(masterdata[c("xcoord", "ycoord")], 
                                       masterdata[c("x_SMP", "y_SMP")])
```

This way, you won't need a for-loop.